# Getting ArrayList object from servlet and storing it as javascript array variable using AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I have some arrayList objects as my servlet request attribute. I want to get it into my ***javascript variable*** which is in a JSP page. I tried like this.

**abc.jsp**

```
<script>
var myList=<% (ArrayList)request.getParameter("list_name") %>;

//do use of myList.....

</script>
```

But this is not working. I am not getting the data.

Then tried with

```
var myList=<% =(ArrayList)request.getParameter("list_name") %>;
```

Didnt work!!

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Thejsp variable should be declared as <%= ArrayList myList=(ArrayList)request.getParameter("list_name") %>.

Comment: Hi Alaa, Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Certainly i have declared my variable like this as this is the usual way of declaring jsp variable as you are saying. <%= ArrayList myList=(ArrayList)request.getParameter("list_name") %>.

Comment: My problem is now how i can use that jsp variable in my javascript, this list is having thousands of records.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `toString()` method of `ArrayList` would accidentally give the desired result, then you can simply use `var myList = ${list_name};`. But the result of your 2nd snippet should also be working, so I would assume that you don't have the list set as a request attribute.

Make sure you've:

- called `request.setAttribute("list_name", yourlist);` in the servlet
- used forward, rather than redirect to the jsp.

You can also try `[${fn:join(list_name, ',')}]`

or

```
var myList = new Array();
<c:forEach items="${list_name}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
   myList[${loop.index}] = "${item}";
</c:forEach>
```